# Android app for decorating destination numbers

Tags: contacts, phone-app

I have set up a IP-PBX with a GSM gateway. This lets me call into my PBX. At this point I reach a IVR. One option lets me forward a call over VOIP by sending a destination.

To automate this I decorated the destination with the gateway number and pauses. As described [about.com](http://cellphones.about.com/od/howtoguides/ss/How-To-Automatically-Dial-Extensions-On-Android.htm).

So I end up having to enter a number for each of my contacts like so:

```
#gatewayNR#,,6,*pass*,#destinationNR#
```

Anybody knows an app who let me do that for Android?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/clickable-phone-number-with-pauses-and-bridge-extension-in-calendar-event

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/how-can-i-connect-to-a-number-with-a-conference-call-code-via-google-voice

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/prepend-phone-numbers-with-a-calling-card-dial-in-number

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like there is an app that can do this: Prefixer. So glad I moved away from ios.

Comment: and verified, Prefixer: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tftbelow.prefixer